# Получение большого объема данных , POST запросы, многопоточность

Tags: многопоточность, c#

Здравствуйте, возникли трудности с задачей,с которой раньше не сталкивался,а именно:

Есть текстовый файл и коды товаров в нем.Задача прочесть файл(т.е код товара), отправить POST запрос с этим кодом и получить данные по товару, если таковые есть.Данные пишутся в другой файл. Вроде ничего сложного,и все работает,но в файле порядка 1.600.000 кодов .В минуту в среднем я получаю данные по 80 товарам(среднее время получения ответа от POST запроса 0.7-1 сек).Поэтому ждать мне такими темпами 2 недели, а этого бы не хотелось.

В связи с этим я поделил программу на параллельные потоки. Каждый поток работает со своим куском файла(который есть новый отдельный файл), читает его и независимо от остальных потоков посылает POST запрос и пишет ответ в свой же другой файл. А потом просто это множ-во файликов собираются в один большой результирующий.И как мне казалось, заработать это должно было на порядок быстрее.Но при кол-во потоков N = 10 время ответа от POST запроса вместо 0.7-1 сек выросло аж до 7-8 сек.При N = 100 70-80 сек. Почему это происходит ? И что можете посоветовать в качестве альтернативной оптимизации, кроме распараллеливания ?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А не упираетесь ли вы в пропускную способность сервера? Отпрофилируйте, выясните, где происходит ожидание. Может, сервер может принимать сразу несколько кодов в одном запросе? Если параллелизация не приводит к ускорению ответа от сервера, она, скорее всего, не нужна.

Comment: А может быть, я если честно не знаю, как это отследить даже.Несколько кодов в 1 запросе...Тоже не совсем представляю видимо.Ведь у меня 1 запрос - это 1 товар . А как я могу от 1 запроса получить несколько html разметок сразу для нескольких товаров ?Что-то туплю.

Comment: Это ваш сервер или какой-то общедоступный сервис?

Comment: Сервер общедоступный.

Код: http://pastebin.com/npEpv2DQ

Comment: @Котик: если мы упираемся в производительность сервера, то не странно: если при `N = 1` за 70 сек. проходило (70 сек. / 0.7 сек/зап) = 100 запросов, то и при `N = 100` за 70 сек. проходит (70 сек. / 70 сек/зап * 100 потоков) = 100 запросов.